# Is there a way to protect specific line of code from merge?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two branches in my project: master and develop.
They both have a config file, which contains my main endpoint and all other API endpoints.
How can I protect a master's line, preventing it's main endpoint from being altered on merge requests from develop?

Comment: You can't. You instead need to do some sort of configuration management. Usually by having multiple environments in your configuration file, or different files for each environment and ignore the one for development, or put your configuration in environment variables.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer, will do that. Also, can you create an answer so I approve it as the right one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is not a configuration manager nor a release manager. It can be forced into those roles, but it will not do them well. There's several ways you can cobble something together, but they're all brittle and complicate the merge process which is already complicated enough.

You *could* remove the lines you do not want to merge, commit, merge, and then put them back. This must be correctly done for every merge.

You *could* do a `git merge -n` and carefully adjust the merge to omit certain lines. Again this must be done every merge.

Probably the best option is to writ a [pre-merge-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit) which adjusts the commit, but now this requires the script works correctly, and everyone working on the project has those client-hooks, and they're kept up to date.

Inevitably, someone will screw it up.

---

Instead, it's better to use a configuration system which supports multiple environments. This could be the steps of the release process like "develop", "test", "staging", and "production". This could also be customizations for different clients.

You can do this as a single file, like [config/database.yml in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database). Or one file for each environment like [config/environments/ in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-rails-components). Or as environment variables as advocated by [The Twelve Factor App](https://www.12factor.net/config). Or any combination. So long as it's your app doing it, not Git.

And unlike complicating the merge process, improved configuration management will have knock on effects to improve the rest of the project.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer! This I guess this will help a lot of people with the same doubt!

Comment: @Rodolfo Yes, it is a very common question.